# Add event listeners to pixels in HTML Canvas Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, p5.js

I have an HTML Canvas that's 500 x 500 pixels (250000 pixels total).

I'm using P5 javascript library to make some designs on the canvas.

I want to:
1) Attach an ID to each pixel 
2) Every time a pixel changes, I want an event to pick up that gives me: the ID of the pixel, the previous color of the pixel, the new color of the pixel, and the timestamp of the change

I've looked through all HTML event listeners and haven't found one that will give me this information - is it possible?

I've got the context of the canvas and the image data before any of the drawing starts with:

```js
// canvas instantiated as the canvas element
let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
let imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
let data = imgData.data
```

I *think* the way to interpret `data` from what I have so far is: it's a 250,000 element array in which each element contains the color of the pixel at that point in time. Next step is to add an event listener which fires every time one of these elements changes, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pixels on a canvas aren't part of the DOM. Generally event handlers are attached to DOM elements. I don't see your approach working.

Comment: I can't imagine any approach to detecting canvas pixel changes that wouldn't require a lot of processing time. You'd need to grab two snapshots of the canvas data, compare them, then spit out events for each change. Since changes are likely to involve many pixels, this is definitely not an efficient strategy from any perspective.

Comment: [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) gives you a "screenshot", which you can compare with a previous "screenshot" (from the past) if you really want to. But there is no built-in event, and p5.js does not [seem](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Events) to supply one either. Of course you can use a timer, [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), but it may be a better idea to describe what you expect from tracking pixel changes.

Comment: I have an API which accepts numbers 1 - 250000 as arguments to an API call and plays a corresponding sound. I want to make an API call with the ID of the pixel that changed every time a pixel changes

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use a websocket that picks up x, y coordinates on mouse movements after an `onMouseDown` (or `onTouchDown`) event on the canvas and streams the coordinates to the server